# Does service account need BQ job user role in the same project as datasets it will query?

Tags: google-bigquery, roles, jobs, service-accounts

My GCP expert tells me that my SA only needs data viewer role in the project in which the datasets I want to query are and that as long as it has job user role in any other project the query job should work.

But when I run the query I get this error:

google.api_core.exceptions.Forbidden: 403 POST https://bigquery.googleapis.com/bigquery/v2/projects/... : Access Denied: Project ... : User does not have bigquery.jobs.create permission in project ....

So does the SA need BQ job user role in exactly the same project where the datasets are?

Comment: your GCP expert is correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your GCP expert is correct!

> as long as it has job user role in any other project ...

You just need to make sure you are running the job from within the project where that SA has job user role. This project will be billed for the cost of running job

Answer (score 2):

In order to avoid the error you are facing, it is necessary to have the bigquery.jobs.create permission, as you can see in the error. You have two options:

1.- [Create a custom](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/creating-custom-roles#iam-custom-roles-testable-permissions-console) role with such a permission.

2.- [Add](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/access-control#bigquery) the BigQuery Job User or BigQuery User role. Both of them have the bigquery.jobs.create permission you need.